# How show button hovering above an image or pressing over it?

Tags: javascript, image, css

I trying to create a mosaic, it's very simple :

[image]

I was thinking in show the `delete` button when the user `hover` over the image.
But my website it's responsive too, so to hover only wouldn't work, I need to show the button when the user click above the image too.

I found [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/jvX9u/) which do the hover part, (I'm terrible with CSS, sorry)
How can I do that in a simple way ?

**Update**
Sorry for the misunderstanding guys. Smartphones, I think, don't have the `hover` functionality, so the user, when click in the image, a button to remove the image would show, then if he press it, the image would be removed, that's what I meant.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. It's easy to get a "button" to appear over the images on hover with CSS alone. But what is the button for? And what do you mean by "clck above the image"?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Smartphones, I think, don't have the `hover` functionality, so the user, when click in the image, a button to remove the image would show, then if he press it, the image would be removed, that's what I meant.

Comment: Apart from the mobile issue, the problem with having an action button on hover is that you don't know you can take that action until you've hovered, and the user may not ever hover. So I would suggest having a "button" permanently visible, say at the bottom of the image, with a semi-transparent background—or if that's not amenable, then directly under the image.

Comment: @ralph.m, that was my first approach from the start, I will try again,.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be done in a simpler and more compatible way without using javascript:

HTML:

```
<div class="show-image">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/egeVq.png" />
  <input class="the-buttons" type="button" value=" Click " />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.show-image
  {
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
  }

div.show-image:hover input
  {
  display: block;
  }

div.show-image input
  {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display:none;
  }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jvX9u/211/

Comment: I didn't really understand the `clicking above the image` bit, if you explain it better I can update my code.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding Frank. Smartphones, I think, don't have the `hover` functionality, so the user, when click in the image, a button to remove the image would show, then if he press it, the image would be removed, that's what I meant.

Comment: If you want the click functionality that can only be achieved with javascript though. Glad to help and that it worked (:

Answer (score 2):

that code uses the library jquery.

For click event, you can use .click method of jquery.

I updated the code of the same example. Look it: http://jsfiddle.net/jvX9u/209/

I've commented the part of hover action, and added the part of click, and another part of mouseout for when the mouse out of the button.

This is the code:

```
jQuery(function() {    
    jQuery(".the-buttons").hide();
    /*jQuery('.show-image').hover(function() {
         jQuery(this).find('.the-buttons').fadeIn(1500);
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.the-buttons').fadeOut(1500); 
    });*/

    jQuery('.show-image').click(function() {
         jQuery(this).find('.the-buttons').fadeIn(1500);
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.the-buttons').fadeOut(1500); 
    });

    jQuery('.show-image').mouseout(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.the-buttons').fadeOut(1500); 
    });
});
```

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go with button in this case. the way i see it, it would look much better if you used a simple anchor like this:

[image]

it can appear on *hover* or *mouseIn* in some corner, you can do this with CSS by using the opacity transition. (from 0 to 1 when mouseIn).

Comment: could you please show me how to do that, please ? I liked your suggestion.